# Is there a way to get a list or dict of all objects that got generated while my code is running and their type in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, variables

When programming in an IDE like Spyder you have something like a variable explorer where you can see which objects got generated and what type they are.
IDLE does not have a variable explorer (as far as I know).

I would like to know if there exists something like `all_variables_dict()` in the following example to get a list or dict with all variables/objects that exist right now in my environment:

```
>>>mystring = str('Hello Mr. String')
>>>myfloat = 3.14159
>>>all_variables_dict()
{'mystring': <class 'str'>, 'myfloat': <class 'float'>}
```

Comment: Almost there. Try `dir()`

Comment: `vars()`? `globals()`? `locals()`?

Comment: @Jeff: I think OP wants `locals()`.